# How is Rust not garbage collected, even though it uses ARC?

Tags: garbage-collection, rust

Rust is advertised as not being a garbage collected language. Though, if I recall correctly, it uses Automatic Reference Counting. I remember reading a thread on Reddit, probably in r/programming on how ARC is a form of garbage collection. And now I'm confused, is it or isn't it? Is Rust garbage collected, or is it not? Can someone please clear this up for me?

Comment: Ohh I see. So it's because of the ownership and borrow thing it knows where to de-allocate stuff?

Comment: Well, I think we say that Rust is not a garbage-collected language because any form of garbage collection (be it reference counting or some tracing GC, which is not yet written) is *optional* - if you don't want to use it, then you don't have to, and you won't suffer from its absence (except in isolated cases, but then again, you are free to use it only in some part of your program, if you want). Languages like Java or Python do not allow not to use their GC and their libraries are heavily dependent on garbage collection, so they are usually called "garbage-collected".

Comment: @metro-man you are right. Thanks to ownership and borrowing Rust can know when things must be deallocated. Sometimes, however, that is not enough.

Comment: *ARC* != `Arc`. Rust's `Arc` means "atomically reference counted" and refers to a particular pointer type that is *optionally used*. It is not the same as ARC, which is just a type of global garbage collector that Objective-C and Swift use.

Comment: The whole ARC thing is a very confusing marketing point.